# How to pass SQL query from GUI and get the results and show results in a table using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

Hi I am planning to create a GUI for users to enter their SQL queries in a text field and get the results once the user enter save button. The results should come out as a table exactly like in database tables.

I'm sorry if this is a very simple question, I have very little knowledge in Python and Django.
How can I do this (how to pass my sql from the text field so that i can query to database?) Please give some suggestions guys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to process your input, and then you can use different python libraries to input into SQL database. I was using **sqlite3**, and it was working pretty well for me.
Here is a page for starters that can help you: https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.ht